# What's wrong with selecting the first div this way

Tags: css

I'm trying to have some css applied for the first div with `id=div1`. When I do `.alldivs:first`, it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

```
<div class="alldivs">
   <div class="onediv" id="div1">
   </div>
   <div class="onediv" id="div2">
   </div>
   <div class="onediv" id="div3">
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There's something ambiguous in this question: Are you trying to select the div with id of "div1" or the first child div? *Right now*, with this code, they're the same thing, but conceptually they're not. If you ever rearrange those blocks, then the accepted answer is going to end up applying to a different div.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to select the first child: `.alldivs>:first-child` should do the trick.

**Edit:**
Su edited my post to say `.alldivs:first-child`. This actually isn't right and I've restored it to what I originally put. The `:first-child` syntax selects the first child of its parent that matches the selector immediately previous to the colon. Therefore, `p:first-child` would match any paragraph that was the first child of its parent. Thus, `.alldivs>` matches any child of `.alldivs` and `:first-child` matches the first one. Please make sure you're correct before editing others posts.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is:

```
.alldivs div:first-child
```

Answer (score 1):

If the div has an id already, just select it by id.

```
#div1 {
   /* yes that's all you need */
}
```

There's no such thing as two elements with the same id (if you're paying attention to the rules), so it doesn't matter if it's first or thirty-first.

If you're looking for the first div no matter what the id, use `.alldivs :first-child`

Here's some reference for further understanding:

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#first-child

Answer (score 0):

`.alldivs` is not a selector, if you wanted to select the first div in the dom it would be `div:first-child` or if you wanted to select the first div with the class onediv it would be `.onediv:first-child`

I hope this helps you